# Where is the object in this clause in Byron's Don Juan?

Tags: meaning, lord-byron, don-juan

From Byron's [Don Juan](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)/Canto_the_Eighth):

> But those who scaled, found out that their advance
>       Was favour'd by an accident or blunder:
>   **The Greek or Turkish Cohorn's ignorance
>
>       Had palisado'd in a way you'd wonder
>
>   To see in forts of Netherlands or France**
>       (Though these to our Gibraltar must knock under) --
>   Right in the middle of the parapet
>   Just named, these palisades were primly set:
>
> So that on either side some nine or ten
>       Paces were left, whereon you could contrive
>   To march; a great convenience to our men,
>       At least to all those who were left alive,
>   Who thus could form a line and fight again;
>       And that which farther aided them to strive
>   Was, that they could kick down the palisades,
>   Which scarcely rose much higher than grass blades.

I first thought that "Ignorance had palisadoed **cohorns** there, just like you may see in forts of Netherlands".

But why is there the possessive **s** after "cohorn"? Okay.. let's try to assume that "Cohorn's ignorance" is subject in this clause. This "ignorance" had "palisadoed" something - but what exactly?

And "palisades not higher than grass blades"? What is he talking about? I can't wrap my mind around this, and thus I fail to understand these three lines. What do they mean, in plain English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Palisado** is an obsolete form of [palisade](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palisade#English), which as a verb means:

> To equip with a palisade

... a palisade (noun) in this context being:

> A wall of wooden stakes, used as a defensive barrier.

As a verb, "palisade" is usually transitive (has an object), but in context its meaning as an intransitive verb is clear: the object is implied without being mentioned. We can get some idea of the usage of the verb by checking the examples on [this Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palisado):

> - 1853, Mary Howitt., *Strife and Peace*:

> > The sea breaks upon this coast against a **palisadoed** fence of rocks and cliffs, around which swarm flocks of polar birds with cries and screams.

> - 1816, Robert Kerr, *A General History and Collection of Voyages and Travels*, Volume 17:

> > At Chaco they had a little earthen fort, with a small ditch **palisadoed** round it, and a few old honeycombed guns without carriages, and which do not defend the harbour in the least.

**Cohorn**, in this verse, apparently refers to the Dutch engineer [Menno van Coehoorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menno_van_Coehoorn). At least according to [Peter Cochran, ed., *Aspects of Byron's Don Juan*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AjZQBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false); in the chapter "Mary Shelley's Fair-Copying of Don Juan", he writes:

> At VIII, 46, 3, 3, Byron has to identify the Dutch engineer as "Cohorn".

Here, it seems that "Cohorn" is being used as a metonym for engineer, otherwise "Greek or Turkish Cohorn" would make no sense. So we have both [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) and [hypallage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage) in the line "The Greek or Turkish Cohorn's ignorance".

---

OK, now let's look at your bolded lines again:

> The Greek or Turkish Cohorn's ignorance
> Had palisado'd in a way you'd wonder
> To see in forts of Netherlands or France

Translating this into "plain English", as you asked for:

> The ignorant Greek or Turkish engineers had done a bad job of fortifying the defences - you wouldn't see that in Dutch or French forts!

The **object** of "palisado'd" here is implied by context: it's the parapet being stormed by "our men". The **subject** is the "ignorance" only via hypallage: it was the Cohorns (engineers) who palisado'd the parapet, but it was their ignorance which screwed up the job.

Comment: Ah! I thought "cohorn" was a portable mortar. I never wondered why it's capitalized. And I construed the wrong meaning for "you'd wonder".

Comment: @CopperKettle "Cohorn" is the most confusing word in this passage, I think. It does seem to mean a portable mortar nowadays, but that doesn't make sense in context; I literally had to Google `what is a cohorn byron` to find some references for this.

Comment: The engineer was [Menno van Coehoorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menno_van_Coehoorn) (1641–1704) and the rhetorical figure is [hypallage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage) (whereby "Cohorn's ignorance" is used to mean "ignorant Cohorn").